# Error: "Cannot capture 'displayRandomWordFromArray' before it is declared" iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

My error is that it "Can't capture 'displayRandomWordFromArray' before it is declared" I don't know what this means and I got this from my teacher. I don't know if he is referring to a UILabel or a button. This is the code.

```
let types = ["Alex", "Straub", "Rusher", "Graser"]

var usedStringIndexs:[Int] = []

func someButtonPressed (button: UIButton) {

    let string = types[displayRandomWordFromArray()]

}

func displayRandomWordFromArray () -> Int {

    var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(types.count)))

    while contains(usedStringIndexs, randomNumber) {

        randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(types.count)))

    }

    usedStringIndexs.append(randomNumber)

    return randomNumber

}
```

Thank you for your effort, if there are any questions just comment them on the question.

The objective of this code is to go through the array randomly without repeating a name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.  I created an IBAction for the button.  I printed "string" to the console.  Now the way your method works, it randomly selects a name once and after 4 button pushes and stops working.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    let types = ["Alex", "Straub", "Rusher", "Graser"]

    var usedStringIndexs:[Int] = []

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        let string = types[displayRandomWordFromArray()]
        println(string)

    }

    func displayRandomWordFromArray () -> Int {

        var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(types.count)))

        while contains(usedStringIndexs, randomNumber) {

            randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(types.count)))

        }

        usedStringIndexs.append(randomNumber)

        return randomNumber
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

This simpler code prints a random name every time:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    let types = ["Alex", "Straub", "Rusher", "Graser"]

    var usedStringIndexs:[Int] = []

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        var randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(types.count)))
        let string = types[randomNumber]
        println(string)
    }
}
```

Comment: The second code does.  I was unsure of what you wanted.  If you describe the desired output, I will add it if your original method was not ideal for your need.

Comment: Thank you very much Steve, it's perfect!